# days overlap based on two conditions

Tags: sas

I have the following dataset, I need to count each id only once based on the highest order achieved into:
mono
dual
2 or more

(for example: if the same patient have drugs with no overlap, another two drugs overlapped= then count this patient one time under 2 drug overlap or dual) based on the presence of one of the two conditions:
overlap of 60 days or more between drugs or if the drugs overlap at two different time periods by 30 days then count them (for example one period they same two drugs overlap by 30 and in another period by 40 days count this id as dual)
the output would be 
mono or one drug : 1 (patient 3 counted here)
dual  or two drugs overlap : 2 (patient 2 and 4 would be counted here)
three or more (patient 1)
I don't need the actual drugs that overlap just a count of the frequency where each patient can be counted once only.
There are a totol of 6 drugs.

```html
data have;
input id drug $ start :mmddyy10. end :mmddyy10.;
format start end mmddyy10.;
cards;
1  a    1/1/2004  4/4/2004
1 b     2/2/2004   6/6/2004
1 d    1/4/2005  4/4/2005
2  a    3/1/2006    4/2/2006
2  b    2/2/2006     5/3/2006
2  c    2/2/2006      4/4/2006
2  d   2/3/2001       4/4/2001
3  a    3/3/2001      4/3/2001
3  b    3/2/2002      4/2/2002
4  a    6/1/2001      8/2/2001
4  b    6/1/2001       7/7/2001
4  a    2/2/2001       4/4/2001
4  b    2/5/2001       3/28/2001
;
run;
```

Comment: Please provide some worked examples of the logic you are attempting to implement, along with any code you've tried so far.

Comment: There are many solutions to this question on communities.sas.com

Comment: https://communities.sas.com/t5/Base-SAS-Programming/Concomitant-drug-medication-use/m-p/339848/highlight/true#M77576

Comment: Thank you Reeza, the post you provided is very helpful but can someone modify it to include the second condition? First: I will be looking for 60 days  continous overlap or 30 days overlap at two different periods